# VS2015 ctp 4 + Roslyn Diagnostic (Breakpoint not being hit)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I am attempting to debug a diagnostic I created in VS2015 ctp4, I have a breakpoint set here

```
 Public Sub AnalyzeNode(          node As SyntaxNode,
                         semanticModel As SemanticModel,
                         addDiagnostic As Action(Of Diagnostic),
                     cancellationToken As CancellationToken
                       ) Implements ISyntaxNodeAnalyzer(Of SyntaxKind).AnalyzeNode
```

I start to run in debug mode, the experimental instance of VS launches I create a console application to use as a testing project. The breakpoint isn't hit, when it should. The breakpoint symbol displays the following message, when you hover over it.

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols being loaded for this document.
```

I've tried resetting both instances.

How to fix?

Comment: Do you see your extension in Tools, Extensions in the Roslyn instance?

Comment: @SLaks I do. I'm just trying the suggestion by Kevin Pilch-Bisson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An early guess is that MEF doesn't know about your extension in the experimental hive. There are a couple of things you can try:

1. In the VS that starts up, go to Tools\Updates and Extensions and delete anything that looks like a stale analyzer.
2. Run `devenv /rootSuffix Roslyn /updateConfiguration` (tells VS to rescan MEF)
3. Run `devenv /rootSuffix Roslyn /resetUserData` (tells VS to delete everything that is user specific.

After any of those I would do a full rebuild of your analyzer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't the switch `/resetUserData` (without the extra `t`)?